# How can I "censor" players on the IGS server?

Tags: go, online

How can censor players on the Internet Go Server (IGS)?

It says in the help you can block players from matches by "censoring" them, but there is no "censor" command.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it only requires computer knowledge, not board-game knowledge.

Comment: @tsuma534 The help center does say "Questions about computer implementations of board games are fine." and we have other questions about computer versions of board games.

Comment: @Jefromi This is a question about a feature that is unique to a specific computer version of the game. Which is unlikely to help anyone but the person asking and they can get better help with the actual services documentation.

Comment: I already said that is not clear from the documentation how to do it. As for the "version", IGS has been using the same software for 20 years and it is the #1 go server in the world, so this is not some transient question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/37930/discussion-between-jefromi-and-joe-w).

Comment: FYI, previous meta post establishing computer-version-only questions as on-topic: http://meta.boardgames.stackexchange.com/q/1193/409

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is about running a computer based board game, not playing it.